# Need admin approval unverified This app may be risky. If you trust this app, please ask your admin to grant you access

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-devops-rest-api, ropc

I have made a web app that using Microsoft Graph API's. when we authenticate user using their personnel account then it work perfectly but when someone use their organizational account then error display which is

> "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '29eb2e50-3e2b-45a4-9488-d9b08a34b6f0' named 'testing app'.
> Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
> Trace ID: 4a665bcf-c19e-48f8-b5c2-056e61aa2d00
> Correlation ID: 1ad728bb-6fa2-4f27-ae5e-215f580d2e9e
> Timestamp: 2022-09-05 10:46:49Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2022-09-05 10:46:49Z","trace_id":"4a665bcf-c19e-48f8-b5c2-056e61aa2d00","correlation_id":"1ad728bb-6fa2-4f27-ae5e-215f580d2e9e","suberror":"consent_required"}

Now kindly let me know how can we resolve it. I have done all changes in our Azure app which is provided by the internet but still the same error. Please let me know which permission I should add or which changes are made to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please copy/paste the error here.  It makes no sense to use an image for text,

Comment: "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '29eb2e50-3e2b-45a4-9488-d9b08a34b6f0' named 'testing app'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 4a665bcf-c19e-48f8-b5c2-056e61aa2d00\r\nCorrelation ID: 1ad728bb-6fa2-4f27-ae5e-215f580d2e9e\r\nTimestamp: 2022-09-05 10:46:49Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2022-09-05 10:46:49Z","trace_id":"4a665bcf-c19e-48f8-b5c2-056e61aa2d00","correlation_id":"1ad728bb-6fa2-4f27-ae5e-215f580d2e9e","suberror":"consent_required"}

Comment: The intention was to make it a better question, so I have copied it for you.  I can't answer it but I have upvoted it, now that it is a better question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I'm facing right now is very similar to the question asked here. Here is the error I got during the sign-in process.

[image]

The problem is clearly mentioned on the app registration page.

> Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers.

It looks like we need to publish our app before signing in from multi-tenant accounts.

Resources:-

- [How to grant access to user to give consent to 3rd party unverified applications for development purpose?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/188721/how-to-grant-access-to-user-to-give-consent-to-3rd)
- [Configure how users consent to applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?pivots=portal#risk-based-step-up-consent)
- [Publisher verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/publisher-verification-overview)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be the administrator of the tenant (if you are not a tenant administrator, you cannot give the administrator permission), you can set up user roles according to [Assign Azure AD roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal).

1.Log in to https://portal.azure.com as a tenant administrator.

2.Open the registration of your application in the following location.

3.Go to settings and then the required permissions.

4.Press the grant permission button.

Check if the user or organizational account has the required permission granted as seen in the sample below.

[image]

Comment: Actually we have azure app in which we give all permission which is required for authentication but when we authenticate user with personnel account then there is no any error but when we authenticate user from their organizational account then it gives permissions error kindly let me know that which permissions we should add for avoid this error thanks.